# Modify Code - Add a permanent CC to MailMerge - Google Sheets / Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to add a permanent CC to the below code. Code below works as intended.

(CC someone@something.com) which I can place in any column in the spreadsheet with the other email addresses it is sending to.

```
function anothertestofamailmerge() {

var Date  = 0;
var NPOName = 2;
var TotalBoxes = 3;
var Email = 4;
var Contact = 5;
var SuggestedVehicle = 8;
var Order = 9;

var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("testofmailmerge");

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MailMerge")

var data = ws.getRange("A2:J" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

data.forEach(function(row){

emailTemp.Date  = row[Date ];
emailTemp.NPOName = row[NPOName];
emailTemp.TotalBoxes = row[TotalBoxes];
emailTemp.Email = row[Email];
emailTemp.Contact = row[Contact];
emailTemp.SuggestedVehicle = row[SuggestedVehicle];
emailTemp.Order = row[Order];

var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();

GmailApp.sendEmail(
  row[Email], 
  "Your Click & Collect Order is READY to be collected!",                   
  "You Email",
  {name: "No Reply Warehouse", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
);

});
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to add `cc` to `GmailApp.sendEmail()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, it supposes that the mail address for `cc` is declared as a variable.

#### Modified script:

```
var ccMailAddress = "someone@something.com";
GmailApp.sendEmail(
  row[Email], 
  "Your Click & Collect Order is READY to be collected!",
  "You Email",
  {name: "No Reply Warehouse", htmlBody: htmlMessage, cc: ccMailAddress}
);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, it supposes that the mail address for `cc` is put to the column "K".

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var data = ws.getRange("A2:J" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

To:

```
var data = ws.getRange("A2:K" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

and

From:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(
  row[Email], 
  "Your Click & Collect Order is READY to be collected!",
  "You Email",
  {name: "No Reply Warehouse", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
);
```

To:

```
var ccMailAddress = row[10];;
GmailApp.sendEmail(
  row[Email], 
  "Your Click & Collect Order is READY to be collected!",
  "You Email",
  {name: "No Reply Warehouse", htmlBody: htmlMessage, cc: ccMailAddress}
);
```

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

As a simple test run, at first, please create new Google Apps Script project. And please copy and paste the following script by setting the email addresses. Then run it.

#### Simple sample script for using `cc`:

```
function myFunction() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    "### email 1 ###",
    "sample subject",
    "sample body",
    {name: "sample", htmlBody: "sample", cc: "### email 2 ###"}
  );
}
```

Comment: いつもTanaikeとしてありがとう-あなたは常に動作するコードを常に通過します。

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for quick replying. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Tanaike - testing is not producing a cc email ? I am using pattern 2. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LiTi9z80ZkwKOsPjC7H-QB2JfRZfQZmS-q7RhfeoxSg/edit#gid=966740048

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. Can you explain about your shared Spreadsheet and script? Because there are a lot of files and sheets. By this, I cannot understand about your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Sorry -  if you look at MailMerge tab, you can see Email in E & CC in K. see script anothertestofamailmerge()

Comment: when I run the code it sends me an email but no cc email

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I saw `MailMerge.gs`. I cannot understand about your issue.

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Where can I see your current script reflected my modified script?

Comment: Tanaike - see script anothertestofamailmerge() - NOT mailmerge.gs

Comment: I have renamed it to A11 - and is at top of scripts

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I could confirm `anothertestofamailmerge()`. I think that in your script works. And also, as a test run, when I modified `row[Email]` and `ccMailAddress` to my email addresses, I could confirm that the email can be sent with `from` and `cc`. So can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: I run the same script but am only getting the one email - still NO CC email. very strange

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. The reason that the your issue is still not resolved is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, how about testing using a simple script? By this, I think that it will help to understand about the script.

Comment: 田池お試しいただきありがとうございます。スクリプトがccで動作しない理由はわかりません。 1通のメールを送信しても正常に機能しますが、ccは送信できません。あなたの言ったことを試してみます。とにかくありがとう。トム

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that your script worked. After you tested the simple script, can you provide your actual script and the detail information of the issue for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: 田池-私は時々とても愚かです。あなたのコードは常に機能し、私はCCの間違ったメールを見ていました。私がチェックし、すべてのCCが到着したことに気付いたとき。貴重な時間を無駄にしたことをおmyび申し上げます。

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that your issue was resolved. If my understanding is correct, I'm glad for it.